# Error while installing Tensorflow in R

Tags: r, tensorflow, installation

I am trying to install Tensorflow in R as explained here- https://github.com/rstudio/tensorflow. I want to use Keras for deep learning in R.

```
devtools::install_github("rstudio/tensorflow") 

library(tensor flow)

install_tensorflow()
```

The first two lines worked but the last line gave the following error:-

```
Error: Prerequisites for installing TensorFlow not available.
```

Any idea how to resolve this? I have installed anaconda and python 3.6. And I am using Mac OS X.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is resolved! I just updated the 'Rcpp' package and gave the path to python using:-

```
reticulate::use_python("/Users/../anaconda/bin/python")
```

I was able to install tensorflow using R.

Comment: Did you also get any warning saying the version is deprecated once you had installed it ?