# Prerequisites for installing TensorFlow not available

Tags: r, macos, tensorflow, terminal

I am trying to install Tensorflow in R as explained here- https://github.com/rstudio/tensorflow. I want to use Keras for deep learning in R.

`devtools::install_github("rstudio/tensorflow") 
 library(tensorflow)
 install_tensorflow()`

but there was an error

`Error: Prerequisites for installing TensorFlow not available. 
 Execute the following at a terminal to install the prerequisites:
 $ sudo /usr/local/bin/pip install --upgrade virtualenv`

i followed the code given to put into terminal but this seems like another error

> The directory '/Users/liangweiteo/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its
>   parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has
>   been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that
>   directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
>   The directory '/Users/liangweiteo/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent
>   directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been
>   disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If
>   executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag. Requirement
>   already up-to-date: virtualenv in
>   /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages

tried to look for help on this site

[Error while installing Tensorflow in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44461041/error-while-installing-tensorflow-in-r)

but somehow the error is still there

Comment: Do you have `virtualenv` installed? You will need it...

Comment: yeap virtualenv was installed
added this in terminal 

`$ virtualenv --system-site-packages targetDirectory`