# Error: Installation of TensorFlow not found

Tags: r, tensorflow

## Overview

I am having trouble loading Python TensorFlow from the `tensorflow` R package.

```r
library(tensorflow)
sess <- tf$Session()
#> Error: Installation of TensorFlow not found.
#> 
#> Python environments searched for 'tensorflow' package:
#>  /home/[username]/anaconda3/envs/r-tensorflow/bin/python3.7
#>  /usr/bin/python2.7
#>  /usr/bin/python2.7
#>  /usr/bin/python3.4
#>  /home/[username]/anaconda3/bin/python3.7
#>  /[censored]/apps/python/python-3.6.5/bin/python3.6
#> 
#> You can install TensorFlow using the install_tensorflow() function.
```

I have fresh local installations of Anaconda 3, Python 3.7.3, and R 3.6.0. I installed TensorFlow by calling `tensorflow::install_tensorflow()` in a fresh R session with no arguments.

## Related

I am aware of related threads and articles, including these.

- https://github.com/rstudio/tensorflow/issues/144
- https://github.com/rstudio/keras/issues/755
- https://tensorflow.rstudio.com/tensorflow/articles/installation.html
- [Error while installing Tensorflow in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44461041/error-while-installing-tensorflow-in-r)

I read them and tried the suggestions, and I am still encountering the same error.

## Configuration

```r
reticulate::py_module_available("tensorflow")
#> FALSE
reticulate::conda_list()
#>           name                                               python
#> 1    anaconda3                   /home/[username]/anaconda3/bin/python
#> 2 r-tensorflow /home/[username]/anaconda3/envs/r-tensorflow/bin/python
reticulate::py_config()
#> python:         /home/[username]/anaconda3/envs/r-tensorflow/bin/python
#> libpython:      /home/[username]/anaconda3/envs/r-tensorflow/lib/libpython3.7m.so
#> pythonhome:     /home/[username]/anaconda3/envs/r-tensorflow:/home/[username]/anaconda3/envs/r-tensorflow
#> version:        3.7.3 (default, Mar 27 2019, 22:11:17)  [GCC 7.3.0]
#> numpy:          /home/[username]/anaconda3/envs/r-tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy
#> numpy_version:  1.16.3
#> tensorflow:     /home/[username]/anaconda3/envs/r-tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow
#> 
#> python versions found: 
#>  /home/[username]/anaconda3/envs/r-tensorflow/bin/python
#>  /bin/python
#>  /usr/bin/python
#>  /usr/bin/python3
#>  /home/[username]/anaconda3/bin/python
#>  /home/[username]/.virtualenvs/python-env/bin/python
devtools::session_info()
#> ─ Session info ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  setting  value                       
#>  version  R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
#>  os       Red Hat Enterprise Linux    
#>  system   x86_64, linux-gnu           
#>  ui       X11                         
#>  language (EN)                        
#>  collate  en_US.UTF-8                 
#>  ctype    en_US.UTF-8                 
#>  tz       America/Indiana/Indianapolis
#>  date     2019-05-06                  
#> 
#> ─ Packages ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  package     * version date       lib source        
#>  assertthat    0.2.1   2019-03-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
#>  backports     1.1.4   2019-04-10 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
#>  base64enc     0.1-3   2015-07-28 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
#>  callr         3.2.0   2019-03-15 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
#>  cli           1.1.0   2019-03-19 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
#>  crayon        1.3.4   2017-09-16 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
#>  desc          1.2.0   2018-05-01 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
#>  devtools      2.0.2   2019-04-08 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
#>  digest        0.6.18  2018-10-10 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
#>  evaluate      0.13    2019-02-12 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
#>  fs            1.3.0   2019-05-02 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
#>  glue          1.3.1   2019-03-12 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
#>  highr         0.8     2019-03-20 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
#>  htmltools     0.3.6   2017-04-28 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
#>  jsonlite      1.6     2018-12-07 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
#>  knitr         1.22    2019-03-08 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
#>  lattice       0.20-38 2018-11-04 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
#>  magrittr      1.5     2014-11-22 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
#>  Matrix        1.2-17  2019-03-22 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
#>  memoise       1.1.0   2017-04-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
#>  pkgbuild      1.0.3   2019-03-20 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
#>  pkgload       1.0.2   2018-10-29 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
#>  prettyunits   1.0.2   2015-07-13 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
#>  processx      3.3.0   2019-03-10 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
#>  ps            1.3.0   2018-12-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
#>  R6            2.4.0   2019-02-14 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
#>  Rcpp          1.0.1   2019-03-17 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
#>  remotes       2.0.4   2019-04-10 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
#>  reticulate    1.12    2019-04-12 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
#>  rlang         0.3.4   2019-04-07 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
#>  rmarkdown     1.12    2019-03-14 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
#>  rprojroot     1.3-2   2018-01-03 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
#>  sessioninfo   1.1.1   2018-11-05 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
#>  stringi       1.4.3   2019-03-12 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
#>  stringr       1.4.0   2019-02-10 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
#>  tensorflow  * 1.13.1  2019-04-05 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
#>  testthat      2.1.1   2019-04-23 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
#>  tfruns        1.4     2018-08-25 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
#>  usethis       1.5.0   2019-04-07 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
#>  whisker       0.3-2   2013-04-28 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
#>  withr         2.1.2   2018-03-15 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
#>  xfun          0.6     2019-04-02 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
#>  yaml          2.2.0   2018-07-25 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
#> 
#> [1] /home/[username]/R/R-3.6.0/library
```

### Edit 1

It appears the version of TensorFlow installed from R (in the `r-tensorflow` virtual env) has trouble loading.

```r
Python 3.7.3 (default, Mar 27 2019, 22:11:17) 
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/[username]/anaconda3/envs/r-tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/home/[username]/anaconda3/envs/r-tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/[username]/anaconda3/envs/r-tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/home/[username]/anaconda3/envs/r-tensorflow/lib/python3.7/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/home/[username]/anaconda3/envs/r-tensorflow/lib/python3.7/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /home/[username]/anaconda3/envs/r-tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/[username]/anaconda3/envs/r-tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "/home/[username]/anaconda3/envs/r-tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/home/[username]/anaconda3/envs/r-tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/[username]/anaconda3/envs/r-tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/home/[username]/anaconda3/envs/r-tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/[username]/anaconda3/envs/r-tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/home/[username]/anaconda3/envs/r-tensorflow/lib/python3.7/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/home/[username]/anaconda3/envs/r-tensorflow/lib/python3.7/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /home/[username]/anaconda3/envs/r-tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so)


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

### Edit 2

I tried `install_tensorflow()` again with the correct version of Python loaded, and `import tensorflow` no longer throws those errors. However, `tf$Session()` still fails. Not sure why yet.

Comment: Hmm... it appears I am encountering https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/26378. I was compiling both Python and TensorFlow against GCC 4.8.5. I can easily opt into GCC 7.3.1 with an environment module. I will go do that and then report back.

Comment: Nope. still does not work. I will edit the main post to include the error message.

Comment: Resolved the compilation issue but still getting the path issue. See Edit 2.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure precisely what the problem was, but I probably should not have tried to install local copies of R, Anaconda, and TensorFlow on top of the recommended stack on an HPC cluster. At the time, I thought I was experiencing some issues that may have arose from routine maintenance on the cluster. Those are resolved, and I am back to successfully using the recommended stack.

The [standard installation instructions](https://tensorflow.rstudio.com/tensorflow/articles/installation.html) work fine for me on all my personal machines. The folks at RStudio put a ton of work into making it easy, and the process is smooth in most instances.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did:

I first installed the [Anaconda](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQbec.png) ensuring that it is in my root path.

I proceeded to install the `tensorflow` and the `reticulate` packages from github using the `devtools` package.

```
# Install devtools
install.packages(“devtools”)

# Install tensorflow:
devtools::install_github(“rstudio/tensorflow”)

# install reticulate:
install.packages("reticulate")
```

The `reticulate` package provides a comprehensive set of tools for ease of interaction between Python and R.

Now load the `reticulate` package:

```
# Load library
library(reticulate)
```

Select the python version you would like to use in your environment. This should sort the problem where you have multiple python versions installed in your system:

```
# Python version
use_python("/usr/local/bin/python")
```

Now, set the virtual environment in which we will perform your analysis:

```
# Python environment:
use_virtualenv("myenv")
```

Now proceed to install `tensorflow`:

```
library(tensorflow)

# Install tensorflow
install_tensorflow()
```

To test if tensforflow has been installed:

```
tf$print(
  tf$constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')
  )
```

Output:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

I ran into this problem. After some days of searching for an answer I tried this:

1. Uninstall Rstudio
2. Uninstall R
3. Uninstall Anaconda
4. Reinstall R (4.0.2)
5. Reinstall Rstudio
6. Install Python (3.8)
7. In R -
   `install.packages("keras")`
   `install_keras()`
   `library("keras")`

- and the problem was solved.